# Virtual Host / Apache Setup on Puppet or Chef, requires re-provisioning?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chef-infra, provisioning, puppet

I am deciding between using puppet or chef to provision a matching development and production environment. I plan to regularly add virtual hosts to apache. I have looked through the docs of both and I am not certain about this. If I add a virtual host, does the server need to be re-provisioned entirely (destroyed / rebuilt) for a new virtual host to be active? Or can I simply reboot the machine and new changes to the puppet or chef manifests will be applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, provisioning can run over and over again, even without reboot.

Chef by default runs every 30 minutes.

Comment: so, if I change the manifest files for example, I could just restart apache and it would take note of the changes and add the virtual host for me?

Comment: Puppet would restart apache for you.

Comment: Does just changing the manifest files trigger puppet to restart apache? Or is it just periodic?

Comment: Chef can restart apache for you. You simply add a [`notification`](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_common_notifications.html) to the vhost resource telling it to restart apache.
It doesn't just restart apache by default because that might not be what you want, but makes it trivial to do so if you like.